# How to send nunit results from jenkins to email

Tags: nunit, jenkins

I've set up my jenkins to send emails after nunit tests are passed. How can I configure that the body of mail contains nunit results from TestResult.xml file? Maybe there is some plugin to jenkins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found suitable solution for me: use Jelly script as described here:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take a look to the [Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin), it will allow you to decide what you want to send (and in your cae attach NUnit report).